# Quick way to find the stabilisers

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

So  I have this and I am trying to work out the stabiliser of the face $abc$.
I know how to find the stabilisers by drawing an action table and by reading of the stabilisers. Drawing an action table would be take too long.

Is their an easier way to find the stabilisers?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't mean "fix the face $abc$ *pointwise*" (to be fixed *pointwise*, none of the vertices $a$, $b$, or $c$ can move), note that all permutations fix the rod. In particular, they fix the intersection of the rod and the face $abc$. Can $abc$ be moved somewhere else, if its center remains fixed?

Assuming you *do* mean "fix the face $abc$ pointwise", can any permutation whose name contains $s$ or $s^2$ leave any of the vertices of $abc$ fixed?